# Our useEffect doesn't call our fetch function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-effect, usecallback

We're trying to fetch data from openweather.org, we want to call a fetch from within a useEffect that runs just once when the page is loaded. We want to be able to call the fetch again from a search form, so to avoid dublicate code we don't want our fetch inside the useEffect function.

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setWeather } from '../actions/weatherAction';
import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import Weather from './weather';

function GetWeather() {
  console.log('what up yo?') // 1. Logs
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const weather = useSelector(state => state.weather);

  console.log(weather) // 2. Logs an empty object as expected

  // async function fetchWeather() {
  //   console.log('fetching')
  //   const response = await fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=stockholm&appid=1dc27327c1655e53a85e6e5a889fccee');
  //   console.log('response:', response);
  //   const data = await response.json();
  //   console.log('data:', data);
  //   dispatch(setWeather(data));
  // } This is what we initially tried together with useEffect(() => { fetchWeather() }, []) which seemed to work sometimes but not every time.

  const fetchWeather = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('fetching'); // 4. Does not log!
    return fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=stockholm&appid=1dc27327c1655e53a85e6e5a889fccee')
      .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => dispatch(setWeather(data)))
  }, [dispatch])

  // useEffect(() => {
  //     console.log('useEffect: ', weather);
  // }, [weather]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('calling fetch'); // 3. Does not log!
    fetchWeather();
  }, [fetchWeather]);
  
  return (
    <main if={ weather.weather }>
      <Weather weather={ weather }/>

      <button onClick={ fetchWeather }>Go!</button>
    </main>
  )
}

export default GetWeather;
```

REDUCER:

```
const initState = {
    weather: {}
};

export const weatherReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_WEATHER':
            return {
                ...state,
                weather: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

ACTION:

```
export const setWeather = (weather) => {
    return {
        type: 'SET_WEATHER',
        payload: weather
    };
};
```

DATA from INSOMNIA:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 2.159,
    "lat": 41.3888
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 291.36,
    "feels_like": 291.01,
    "temp_min": 288.47,
    "temp_max": 293.7,
    "pressure": 1017,
    "humidity": 68
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 0.45,
    "deg": 307,
    "gust": 4.02
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 0
  },
  "dt": 1622266137,
  "sys": {
    "type": 2,
    "id": 2003688,
    "country": "ES",
    "sunrise": 1622262117,
    "sunset": 1622315758
  },
  "timezone": 7200,
  "id": 3128760,
  "name": "Barcelona",
  "cod": 200
}
```

STORE (index.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { weatherReducer } from './reducers/weatherReducer';

const store = createStore(weatherReducer);

console.log(store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

After reading through another question on this topic we tried with useCallback, but to no avail. We're able to fetch our data with Insomnia though.

Comment: What is `weather` on the first render? It might be `null` or `undefined ` and maybe the first render (before the effect) runs) throws an error because the code assumes it to be set.

Comment: It should return an empty object, but it doesn't seem to return anything. The console.log within useEffect doesn't log at all.

UPDATE:

I console logged it just after defining it and it logs an empty object.

Comment: @crashdelta i replicate your code into codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-framework-pskee  but it doesn't seem to have any problem, am i missing something ?

Comment: That's weird 'cause my whole app crashes and claims that 'weather' is undefined. UPDATE: Actually it says 'temp' of 'weather.main.temp' is undefined.

Comment: I included the data from Insomnia.

Comment: Turned out to be an async problem, the Wheather component was rendered before the state was set. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 3):

Please remove `fetchWeather` from `useEffect` array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('calling fetch');
    
    fetchWeather();
  }, []);
```

The problem here is, `useEffect` is called when `fetchWeather` data is initialize or updated (when you put `[fetchWeather]` on `useEffect`). Since `fetchWeather` is initialized and called inside the `useEffect`, it did nothing.
Now, useEffect function is called when `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUdate`.

Please find more rules of using react hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

EDIT: Real Solution to the problem(*assuming JSX, action and reducer are working fine*):

```
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import { setWeather } from '../actions/weatherAction';
    import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import Weather from './weather';
    
    function GetWeather() {
      const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState(false);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      {/*Make sure your action, reducer are working perfectly*/}
      const weather = useSelector(state => state.weather);
      
      useEffect(() => {
        if(fetchData) dispatch(setWeather());
      }, [fetchData]);
      
      return (
        <main if={ weather.weather }>
          <Weather weather={ weather }/>
    
          <button onClick={()=>setFetchData(true)}>Go!</button>
        </main>
      )
    }
    
    export default GetWeather;
```

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error with 'weather' being undefined plus the ESlint error with missing dependency is back.

Comment: on the above solution, Please make sure your action, reducer, and saga are working fine or post them on the question.

Comment: @crashdelta try above solution now

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve it either, I'm getting even more errors with missing dependencies now and it says 'data is not defined' and 'return data' is greyed out.

Comment: try the recent update, make sure your action and reducer file is working.

Comment: Thing is it was working at first, then it just stopped working. I thought it could be a problem with too many requests to the API but it turned out I could fetch using Insomnia with the same api-key just fine.

Comment: If so, seems like the problem is not in API, the problem is somewhere in action/reducer/saga. I assume you are using saga as well. If possible, please post the saga code as well.

Comment: Yes, the API doesn't seem to be the problem. I wasn't aware of anything called saga. We've only been studiyng react for a few weeks and we haven't covered anything called saga yet.

Comment: There is no function to put value in your  useSelector(state => state.weather)` from API (i.e. it's needed to fetch data from API). If you want to use API directly, there is no need to use useSelector to get data, you can use `fetchWeather()` and get data directly from it (which is currently not right either).

Comment: Just to clarify, this is an excercise from school and using redux is required. I know this can probably be done without redux all together.

Comment: Turned out to be an async problem, the Weather component was rendered before the state was set. Thanks for taking the time.